# Ignore invalid foreign for django migrations?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, migration

I'm migrating an application from an old DB system to django. I've imported a bunch of legacy data. I used a script to convert the table schemas from the old system into Django models, as it had a lots of tables. Then I used another script to write the content of the old db into Django fixtures, which I then imported. That all worked fine, the data is served in the views etc.

However, I now noticed that some ForeignKey in the old system were not properly identified as FK and were simply put in as Char/Int fields into the djando models. So I updated a field from IntegerField to ForeignKey, but that being legacy data I had the following issue:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: The row in table 'pickings_detpick' with primary key '17170' has an invalid foreign key: pickings_detpick.fk_ent_id contains a value '30223' that does not have a corresponding value in pickings_entpick.id.
```

So basically, there are a number of (unsure how many yet) foreign key references that point to objects that actually do not exist in the source data (for whatever reason, I don't know the hold system much).

Is there a way that I can simply tell Django to ignore those & set them as null or something? Or do I actually have to comb thru the data & fix them?

Comment: It would be simplest to do this in the database using some query yourself (don't use Django). Write some SQL that will perform a left / right join and with the where clause select those rows for which the referred object does not exist and set these to null / delete as per your preference. No need to manually comb the data SQL is very powerful :)

Comment: I could do that. My preference would still be to do this in django if at all possible. My 2nd option would be to script the fixtures to find them & set them to null (since I'll then allow null=True in the FK fields). My last option would be to do it straight in sql. IMO django is meant as an sql/db abstraction. It  doesn't make sense to get down to that level unless absolutely necessary - like I wouldn't got mess around with internals  of http protocol to write a web service.....

Comment: Yes the ORM is meant to abstract SQL operations. But if you are somewhat experienced with Django you would know that arbitrary joins are not (easily) possible in Django using the ORM. In fact this is a one time only fix that you have to perform writing a query for that would not be too hard. If you insist on doing this with Django you would have to perform multiple queries to the database and perform joins yourself in python (might as well go for that script option of yours instead of this). This is quite inefficient compared to writing a simple query.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/migration-operations/#runsql

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yes I know some things can't  easily be done with Django. The data structure isn't that complicated, so FK, mtm are enough for the purpose. I'm just not keen on bringing up sql queries on the side given it's not required elsewhere for the project and I already have a pipeline that handles that same data.

Answer (score 0):

Not a long term fix, but on the narrow question to let the constraint slide [the db_constraint](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.db_constraint) attribute of the ForeignKey field would work (set it to False).

Not a good idea in production, and the underlying data still needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
db_constraint=False,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True
```

Also if it still gives an error delete the last 1 or few migrations then do `makemigrations` and migrate it solved my problem.